# Slope of the tangent

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line, slope

I have the following exercise.

$1$. Find the slope of the tangent to the curve $y = x^3  -4x + 1$  at the point where $x = a$.

$2$. Find the equations of the tangent lines in the points $(1, -2)$ and $(2,1)$.

$3$. Graph the curve and the two tangents in a single Cartesian plane.

I understand perfectly how to elaborate the answers for $2$nd and $3$rd part, but I have doubts about how  the first part should be answered: Find the slope of the tangent to the curve $y = x^3  -4x + 1$ at the point where $x = a$.

Could you please help me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the derivative at $a$?

Comment: `I understand perfectly how to elaborate the answers for 2nd and 3th part` Use one of those to find the tangent at point $(a, a^3-4a+1)$.

Comment: Can you get started with the third part at all?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

1. Remember that the slope in a point x is given by $f'(x)$
2. The line equation in  a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is $(y-y_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$

Comment: the slope of the tangent to the curve y=x slope of the tangent to the curve y=x3−4x+1 at the point where x=a3−4x+1 at the point where x=a   is  m=3a^2-4. is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly! $m=3a^2-4$ is the slope

Answer (score 0):

(1)  Find $\,f'$(x)  and then substitute x = a as the derivative of a function at a point is equal to the tangent slope at that  point. You're supposed to get 3a$^2$-4.

(2) You can use the point-slope form of a line ie   $\,y-y_0 = \frac{dy}{dx}.(x-x_0) $ where $\,(x_o,y_0)$ are the given points.

Here the equations should simplify to $\,y = -(x+1)$ and $\, y= 8x-15$

(3)[image]